# Migrate sharepoint item along with its versions

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

In my project I am migrating Sharepoint items from source site to destination site. I need to maintain all versions of the source file.
My approach for the migration of sharepoint item is as follow.

1. Read source file data
2. Create new file at destination
3. write file data at destination file.
4. Read source file version one by one
5. Add version at destination file.

Here I am able to upload the file version. But my it overwrites the current version of destination file. I need to add the file version without changing its current version. How can I achieve it?

```
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(srcVersiondataBytes))
    {    
        SPFile.SaveBinaryDirect(clientcontext, destServerRelativeUrl, memoryStream, true);
     }
    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it for office 365 or SharePoint on premise ?